# link to a shared folder in google drive that automatically opens the first element

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

as stated in the object I would like to know if anyone has some tips on how to create a link to a shared folder in google drive that automatically opens the first element.

I mean: when I open the shared link of a public folder, I get the folder page where I see thumbs or list of the file inside of it. 
When I click on the first (or anyelse) item into the folder, the gallery of files starts.

What I would need is a link (or maybe a script? unlickily I am not very skilled in javascript) that automatically let start the google drive presentation of the files inside the shared folder.
Any suggestion or also statement about (un)feasibility to do that is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Federico

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole API for Google Drive that you can use to interrogate folders and files and download what you need. The starting point is the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk).

Unfortunately, that requires using some JavaScript (or another supported language).

Comment: Thank you Cobus. Yesterday night I took a look at API of Google Drive, but it seems to me that these are intended more for who wants to build some apps. I don't know exactly what Google means with this (trendy) term, as sometimes also a webpage can be an app; anyway reading the main api page, they talk about creation of apps that users should install, so maybe something different than a simpler webpage, that is what I would like to do. But maybe I could also be wrong, as I don't have read everything about GD Api.

Comment: You're not limited to apps and can definitely do it from a web page as well, but you indicated that you're not great in JavaScript, which you'll definitely need.